# How can I build an HTML org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: java, html, xml, dom

The [documentation of the `Document` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) describes the interface as:

> The Document interface represents the entire HTML or XML document.

`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` builds XML `Document`s.  However, I am unable to find a way to build a `Document` that is an HTML `Document`!

I want an HTML `Document` because I am trying to build a document that I then pass to a library that is expecting an HTML `Document`. This library uses `Document#getElementsByTagName(String tagname)` in a non case-sensitive manner, which is fine for HTML, but not for XML.

I've looked around, and am not finding anything. Items like [How to convert an Html source of a webpage into org.w3c.dom.Document in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297924/how-to-convert-an-html-source-of-a-webpage-into-org-w3c-dom-document-in-java) don't actually have an answer.

Comment: You might have the XMLSerializer available. https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xml/serialize/XMLSerializer.html

Comment: I think what I was looking for was https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/html/dom/HTMLDocumentImpl.html. Not sure yet, though.

Comment: @dimadima That's what I was thinking, too, at first, but not so much now.  I'll try to write up an answer later explaining why and a possible alternative.

Comment: @dimadima I posted an answer of what I have found out so far.  If I found out more or corrections, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You seem to have two explicit requirements:

1. You need to represent HTML as a `org.w3c.dom.Document`.
2. You need `Document#getElementsByTagName(String tagname)` to operate in a case-insensitive manner.

If you are trying to work with HTML using [`org.w3c.dom.Document`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), then I assume you are working with some flavor of XHTML.  Because an XML API, such as DOM, is going to expect well-formed XML.  HTML isn't necessarily well-formed XML, but XHTML is well-formed XML.  Even if you were working with HTML, you would have to do some pre-processing to ensure it is well-formed XML before trying to run it through an XML parser.  It might just be easier to parse the HTML first with an HTML parser, such as [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), and then build your `org.w3c.dom.Document` by walking through the HTML parser's produced tree (`org.jsoup.nodes.Document` in the case of jsoup).

---

There is an [`org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) interface, which extends `org.w3c.dom.Document`.  The only implementation I found was in [Xerces-j](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j) (2.11.0) in the form of [org.apache.html.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/html/dom/HTMLDocumentImpl.html).  At first this seems promising, however upon closer examination, we find that there are some issues.

**1. There is not a clear, "clean" way to obtain an instance of an object implementing the `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument` interface.**

With Xerces we normally would obtain a `Document` object using a `DocumentBuilder` in the following fashion:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.newDocument();
//or doc = builder.parse(xmlFile) if parsing from a file
```

Or using a `DOMImplementation` variety:

```
DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS)registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
LSParser lsParser = impl.createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, null);
Document document = lsParser.parseURI("myFile.xml");
```

In both cases, we are purely using `org.w3c.dom.*` interfaces to obtain the `Document`object.

The closest equivalent I found for `HTMLDocument` was something like this:

```
HTMLDOMImplementation htmlDocImpl = HTMLDOMImplementationImpl.getHTMLDOMImplementation();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = htmlDocImpl.createHTMLDocument("My Title");
```

This requires us to directly instantiate internal implementation classes making us implementation dependent on Xerces.

*(Note: I also saw Xerces also had an internal `HTMLBuilder` (which implements the deprecated `DocumentHandler`)  that can supposedly generate an `HTMLDocument using a SAX parser, but I didn't bother looking into it.`)*

**2. `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument` does not generate proper XHTML.**

Although, you can search the `HTMLDocument` tree using `getElementsByTagName(String tagname)` in a case-insensitive manner, all of the element names are saved internally in *ALL CAPS.*   But XHTML elements and attribute names are supposed to be in [all lowercase](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2).  (This could be worked around by walking the entire document tree and using `Document`'s `renameNode()` method to change all of the element's names to lowercase.)

Additionally, an XHTML document is supposed to have a proper [DOCTYPE declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict) and [xmlns declaration for the XHTML namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict) .  There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to set those in an `HTMLDocument` (unless you do some fiddling with internal Xerces implementations).

**3. `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument` has little documentation, and Xerces implementation of the interface seems incomplete.**

I didn't scour the entire Internet, but the only documentation I found for `HTMLDocument` was the previously linked JavaDocs, and comments in the source code of the Xerces internal implementation.  In those comments, I also found notes that several different parts of the interface weren't implemented.  *(Sidenote: I really got the impression that the `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument` interface itself isn't really used by anyone and perhaps is incomplete itself.)*

---

For those reasons, I think it's better to avoid `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument` and just do what we can with `org.w3c.dom.Document`.  What can we do?

Well one approach is to extend `org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl` (which extends `org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl` which implements `org.w3c.dom.Document`).  This approach doesn't require much code, but it still makes us implementation dependent on Xerces since we are extending `DocumentImpl`.  In our `MyHTMLDocumentImpl`, we are just converting all tag names to lowercase on element creation and searches.  This will allow use of `Document#getElementsByTagName(String tagname)` in a case-insensitive manner.

`MyHTMLDocumentImpl`:

```
import org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl;
import org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentTypeImpl;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.DocumentType;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

//a base class somewhere in the hierarchy implements org.w3c.dom.Document
public class MyHTMLDocumentImpl extends DocumentImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1658286253541962623L;


    /**
     * Creates an Document with basic elements required to meet
     * the <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict">XHTML standards</a>.
     * <pre>
     * {@code
     * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     * <!DOCTYPE html 
     *     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
     *     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     * <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     *     <head>
     *         <title>My Title</title>
     *     </head>
     *     <body/>
     * </html>
     * }
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param title desired text content for title tag. If null, no text will be added.
     * @return basic HTML Document. 
     */
    public static Document makeBasicHtmlDoc(String title) {
        Document htmlDoc = new MyHTMLDocumentImpl();
        DocumentType docType = new DocumentTypeImpl(null, "html",
                "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd");
        htmlDoc.appendChild(docType);
        Element htmlElement = htmlDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html");
        htmlDoc.appendChild(htmlElement);
        Element headElement = htmlDoc.createElement("head");
        htmlElement.appendChild(headElement);
        Element titleElement = htmlDoc.createElement("title");
        if(title != null)
            titleElement.setTextContent(title);
        headElement.appendChild(titleElement);
        Element bodyElement = htmlDoc.createElement("body");
        htmlElement.appendChild(bodyElement);

        return htmlDoc;
    }

    /**
     * This method will allow us to create a our
     * MyHTMLDocumentImpl from an existing Document.
     */
    public static Document createFrom(Document doc) {
        Document htmlDoc = new MyHTMLDocumentImpl();
        DocumentType originDocType = doc.getDoctype();
        if(originDocType != null) {
            DocumentType docType = new DocumentTypeImpl(null, originDocType.getName(),
                    originDocType.getPublicId(),
                    originDocType.getSystemId());
            htmlDoc.appendChild(docType);
        }
        Node docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
        if(docElement != null) {
            Node copiedDocElement = docElement.cloneNode(true);
            htmlDoc.adoptNode(copiedDocElement);
            htmlDoc.appendChild(copiedDocElement);
        }
        return htmlDoc;
    }

    private MyHTMLDocumentImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Element createElement(String tagName) throws DOMException {
        return super.createElement(tagName.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public Element createElementNS(String namespaceURI, String qualifiedName) throws DOMException {
        return super.createElementNS(namespaceURI, qualifiedName.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public NodeList getElementsByTagName(String tagname) {
        return super.getElementsByTagName(tagname.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public NodeList getElementsByTagNameNS(String namespaceURI, String localName) {
        return super.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespaceURI, localName.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public Node renameNode(Node n, String namespaceURI, String qualifiedName) throws DOMException {
        return super.renameNode(n, namespaceURI, qualifiedName.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.w3c.dom.DOMConfiguration;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;


public class HTMLDocumentTest {

    private final static int P_ELEMENT_NUM = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) //I'm throwing all my exceptions here to shorten the example, but obviously you should handle them appropriately.
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassCastException, IOException {

        Document htmlDoc = MyHTMLDocumentImpl.makeBasicHtmlDoc("My Title");

        //populate the html doc with some example content
        Element bodyElement = (Element) htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < P_ELEMENT_NUM; ++i) {
            Element pElement = htmlDoc.createElement("p");
            String id = Integer.toString(i+1);
            pElement.setAttribute("id", "anId"+id);
            pElement.setTextContent("Here is some text"+id+".");
            bodyElement.appendChild(pElement);
        }

        //get the title element in a case insensitive manner.
        NodeList titleNodeList = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tItLe");
        for(int i = 0; i < titleNodeList.getLength(); ++i)
            System.out.println(titleNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());

        System.out.println();

        {//get all p elements searching with lowercase
            NodeList pNodeList = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for(int i = 0; i < pNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
                System.out.println(pNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        {//get all p elements searching with uppercase
            NodeList pNodeList = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("P");
            for(int i = 0; i < pNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
                System.out.println(pNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        //to serialize
        DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");

        LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        DOMConfiguration domConfig = lsSerializer.getDomConfig();
        domConfig.setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);  //if you want it pretty and indented

        LSOutput lsOutput = domImplLS.createLSOutput();
        lsOutput.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        //to write to file
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile.html"))) {
            lsOutput.setByteStream(os);
            lsSerializer.write(htmlDoc, lsOutput);
        }

        //to print to screen
        System.out.println(lsSerializer.writeToString(htmlDoc)); 
    }

}
```

Output:

```
My Title

Here is some text1.
Here is some text2.
Here is some text3.

Here is some text1.
Here is some text2.
Here is some text3.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="anId1">Here is some text1.</p>
        <p id="anId2">Here is some text2.</p>
        <p id="anId3">Here is some text3.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Another approach similar to the above is to instead make a `Document` wrapper that wraps a `Document` object and implements the `Document` interface itself.  This requires more code than the "extending `DocumentImpl`" approach, but this way is "cleaner" as we don't have to care about particular `Document` implementations.  The extra code for this approach isn't difficult; it's just a bit tedious to provide all those wrapper implementations for the `Document` methods.  I haven't completely worked this out yet and there may be some problems, but if it works, this is the general idea:

```
public class MyHTMLDocumentWrapper implements Document {

    private Document doc;

    public MyHTMLDocumentWrapper(Document doc) {
        //...
        this.doc = doc;
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

---

Whether it's `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument`, one of the approaches I mentioned above, or something else, maybe these suggestions will help give you an idea of how to proceed.

---

**Edit:**

In my parsing tests while trying to parse the following XHTML file, Xerces would hang down in an entity management class trying to open an http connection.  Why I don't know?  Especially since I tested on a local html file with with no entities.  (Maybe something to do with the DOCTYPE or namespace?)  This is the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="anId1">Here is some text1.</p>
        <p id="anId2">Here is some text2.</p>
        <p id="anId3">Here is some text3.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi dbank, thanks for this answer! I was, indeed, running the raw html through jsoup first to build an `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`. Then I was converting that into an `org.w3c.dom.Document` by walking the nodes and of the jsoup `Document` and creating analogous nodes for a xerces 2 `HTMLDocumentImplementation`. Anyway, it all proved too unsavory for me in that moment, and I never even tested whether it worked in terms of case-sensitive querying :). Thank you for your answer! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @dimadima:   I just made an edit.  The `MyHTMLDocumentImpl.createFrom(Document doc)` actually seems to work ok.  But the Xerces DOM parser seems to hang on parsing the example XHTML file.

Comment: @dimadima:  Anyway, it's all use at your own risk.  I hope it helps, though.  :-)

Comment: I think I know now why Xerces DOM parser seemed to hang on parsing the example XHTML file.  It actually eventually parses after the long hang.  I will try to edit the answer with an explanation and possible solution when I have time.