# Is JavaFX a better way to create a html report

Tags: html, javafx

I have a Swing application, one thing it does is create an html report that then opens in a browser. Creating this html report within Java and having to write Javascript ectera is hard work. I notice that javafx is now included in Java and I wonder if I could use javafx to create the html report instead and would that be a good idea.

Comment: Is it possible? Probably. Is it easier? Maybe. Is it better? Depends who you ask... I feel like the question, as it is asked now, is too broad to answer...

Comment: What is the question is about? To actually create the report? In this case: what kind of report? What should it contain? As @sillyfly mentions: as the question is asked now, it is impossible to be answered.

Comment: I realize its quite a broad question but also quite straightforward. Is Javafx a better way of creating html from java than writing html directly, the exact nature of the html doesnt really matter that much. But Im not clear if it can be done and if thsi is the kind of thing it is designed to do at the moment.

Comment: "Better" by what criteria? This question is opinion-based, at best. This is not a programming question within the scope of this site.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but I suspect the answer is no - despite the similarities between FXML and HTML, JavaFX does not natively "compile" to HTML or use HTML for rendering. There is a JavaFX `WebView` node, but it does the opposite - render HTML inside JavaFX.  
It sounds like your question is based on confusion around what JavaFX actually is (initial versions were more like something inside a browser AFAIK, but it has not been the case for a long time). As I see it, the creation of HTML inside Java is almost entirely independent of the UI framework/toolkit used.

Comment: You are right I am confused it is stated that JavaFx can create both rich desktop appplications and web applications but I am very unclear of its main purpose. Currenlty I directly write html (i.e <td>, <br> ectera) and I thought in Java I amy be able to extract to a slightly higher level.

Comment: Rather than writing directly the HTML code, you can build a DOM, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041855/how-can-i-build-an-html-org-w3c-dom-document). Also, if your are storing the results in a class structure that should be exported to be an HTML report, you could serialize it to XML using JAXB, which will create the XML representation of your results, then you could use XLS transformation to transform the XML to HTML. I used the second approach several times - it is really convenient if you know XSL.

Comment: @DVarga  okay I think i have found a solution the library https://j2html.com/ works in a similar way to your DOM idea but looks easier to use. My data could be converted to XML and I appreciate that XSL is quite powerful  but It would be a complex XSL to move from XML to HTML and difficult to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it seems I have misunderstopod JavaFX. I thought it was a way to create fancy html applications, but it seems it is more a way to create desktop applications but using technologies familiar to html like CSS to create UI's currently difficult with Swing technology.

For dynamic creating html I am finding the [j2html](https://j2html.com/) library useful.